# Model evaluation based on WoE: test and train set

Tags: logistic, classification, data-transformation, dataset

I am training Logistic Regression model. First, I prepare the variables. I am confused with the following:

Should I transform variables to the ones with WoE (Weight of Evidence) values based on the train set only and then make a corresponding transformation of the variables in the test set?

For me it seems reasonable, but from what I have read people make WoE transformation based on the whole data set and then they split it to train-test sets.